Why does the necessary key combination to zoom in/out change while using Apple Maps?
When using Maps on my iMac, I'm able to zoom in/out using only +/- when I first open the app. However, after requesting directions to a location, I need to use CMD-(+/-) to zoom in/out, even after I close out the directions.
Why do the controls change, and what can I do to change this behavior?
